# Invite facebook friends using SocialNetwork.Framework

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

I have an iOS app that has Socialnetwork.framework integrate. Now what i want is to invite friends using the same. Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to implement Facebook SDK in order to do that.

Comment: Then is it possible to use the current implementation also integrate facebook sdk and not to ask the user to re login.